# Modular Exponentiation in Java

Tags: java, math, modulus, dsa, exponentiation

I need a way to calculate:

```
(g^u * y^v) mod p
```

in Java.

I've found this algorithm for calculating (g^u) mod p:

```
int modulo(int a,int b,int c) {
    long x=1
    long y=a;
    while(b > 0){
        if(b%2 == 1){
            x=(x*y)%c;
        }
        y = (y*y)%c; // squaring the base
        b /= 2;
    }
    return (int) x%c;
}
```

and it works great, but I can't seem to find a way to do this for

```
(g^u * y^v) mod p
```

as my math skills are lackluster.

To put it in context, it's for a java implementation of a "reduced" DSA - the verifying part requires this to be solved.

Comment: yes, p is prime, I think this solves it: (g^u * y^v) mod p = (g^u mod p) * (y^v mod p) mod p, though I have only tested it with small numbers so far

Comment: And is it large? The `mod p` part looks to me like if you wanted to use `BigInteger` instead of long.

Comment: yes, p is large (in my case, 23929 to be specific)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the two factors will not overflow, I believe you can simplify an expression like that in this way:

`(x * y) mod p = ( (x mod p)*(y mod p) ) mod p`. I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Comment: yes, I think this is the way, so far I've done tests on small numbers with this, and it seems to be working

Comment: I'm guessing that it's probably not OK to assume that the factors will not overflow, but I can't be sure.

Comment: The factors will not overflow as long as (p-1)*(p-1) fits inside an `int`. Otherwise, we will just have to use `long`s for x and y. The fact

Answer (score 4):

That fragment of code implements the well known "fast exponentiation" algorithm, also known as [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

It also uses the fact that (a * b) mod p = ((a mod p) * (b mod p)) mod p. (Both addition and multiplications are preserved structures under taking a prime modulus -- it is a homomorphism). This way at every point in the algorithm it reduces to numbers smaller than p.

While you could try to calculate these in an interleaved fashion in a loop, there's no real benefit to doing so.  Just calculate them separately, multiply them together, and take the mod one last time.

Be warned that you will get overflow if p^2 is greater than the largest representable int, and that this will cause you to have the wrong answer.  For Java, switching to big integer might be prudent, or at least doing a runtime check on the size of p and throwing an exception.

Finally, if this is for cryptographic purposes, you should probably be using a library to do this, rather than implementing it yourself.  It's very easy to do something slightly wrong that appears to work, but provides minimal to no security.

Comment: It is indeed for cryptographic purposes, but it is for a school assignment where we are to implement the DSA ourselves. Thank you for your insightful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try

> (Math.pow(q, u) * Math.pow(y, v)) % p

Comment: I'm guessing the reason that he is asking is that the numbers are too big for the simple approach to work...

Comment: If that is the case, why not use BigInteger?

Comment: Math.pow() takes and returns doubles.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that inputs the variables in the original question and follows on from Christian Mann's answer.
BigInteger gets around the overflow issues.
The return statement is a BigInteger.

```
    public static BigInteger ModularExponent(BigInteger G, BigInteger U, BigInteger Y, BigInteger V, BigInteger P) {
      
      return ((G.modPow(U,P)).multiply(Y.modPow(V,P))).mod(P);
    }
```